# How to add 2 numbers in sql Select clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have this query:

```
Select 
    Count(DocumentID) 
From 
    Documents d 
Inner Join 
    Accounts a on a.AccountID = d.CreatedByAccountID  
Where 
    a.FeeExempt = 1
    Or
    (Select 
         Case 
             When a.OrganizationTypeID = 1 Or a.OrganizationTypeID = 2 
             Then 0 
             Else EFileFee 
         End 
     From ITypes
     Where ITypeID = d.ITypeID  

    +
    Select 100 --just to test
    ) <= 0
```

How can I make this query compile? Basically I want to do 2 selects and check if addition of both of them is less than 0 or not. But obviously at the moment the query is incorrect and won't compile.

Comment: You want all rows where `FeeExempt = 1` or the subquery returns 100?

Comment: @Tim: May be yes, but my question is only how to use + operator with Select.

Comment: It is basically a 2nd query from different table. So for ex. instead of Select 100, it could be *Select someIntDBColumn From XYZtable*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want this:

```
. . ..
(select sum(val)
 from ((Select (Case When a.OrganizationTypeID = 1 Or a.OrganizationTypeID = 2 Then 0 Else EFileFee End) as val
        From ITypes
        Where ITypeID = d.ITypeID 
       ) union all
       (Select 100 --just to test
       )
      ) t
 ) <= 0
```

Comment: Perfect!! I think you answered it before I asked ;)